# php photo not retrived correctlly from Database(sql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i am trying to retrieve products photo in is displayed in this format

```
�����z@Y��oEZ�;���Fп����9 ���*Mȷ^����oٴI_�U6j9��+�`��fk�9ג�>.g����8�۰)��(�{c\xW Q_�ZJ��4Q"h�ݭInzzmVIR�o����P��]~D�w��H���抴' ��ݍ�~�_q�\���?]Z�&1��]���y+i�]�f��4fxo�z���M'��S��=.�==Y�^=�;����ZC��9��6EZ�̾�|S� �:�d����y6u�*�j�V�,��}9����`�yu.���/fgbǵ�b�\si��������y���\���g��:];r���Ҿ<{'���Ϫmw�ӽ%��Q��f=.������¹��y�����.�!���5��r�>��Nߌ�C�~܅|_���t���OqѹO&��zx���?
```

can anyone help to convert it or get it in the right format?
this is how i retrieve the photo from the database

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($qry_result))
{
 // each row returned from the query echo into individual columns for the table 
  for($i = 0; $i < 30; ){
    if(!(($i++) % 3)){
        <img  src='.$row->product_photo.' alt=""  />
```

Comment: You can't save binary files as ascii and expect them to still work.

Comment: the photo is uploaded properly in sql but when trying to get it and display it in html is in this format

Comment: one of the reasons its not recommended to store an image in the db, store the file in a directory and its name\location in the db

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a url to retrieve the image:

```
<img  src='//mysite.com/photos.php?id=myphoto' alt=""  />
```

Then in your photos.php script you have your code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($qry_result))
{
  header("Content-Type: application/jpeg"); //or whatever type it is
  echo $row[0]->product_photo;
```

You'll need to adapt this to your needs. But, basically you can't just load the binary data in the src attribute.

Comment: your `for` and `if` make no sense

Comment: The for loop and if would be in the page that shows the `<img>` tag, not in the page that spits out the image, so take all that nonsense out.

Comment: Also probably not necessary to include a full path on the img src. `<img  src='photos.php?id=myphoto' />` would suffice.

Comment: @Dragon, yea, I just used his code. He's just trying to dump a binary blob into a src attr.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is due to an encoding problem,

first be sure that the sql database is utf8_general_ci , also maybe the php file encoding is utf8 sans BOM which will be not compatible with utf8 encoding so open notepad++ then encoding and change it to utf8 instead of utf8 without BOM. I hope this can help.